# Red means go, green means danger

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Bitterly regret the quip, poisonous part of stage chatter goes away. (7, 6)

Comment: enumeration please?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Enumerated. If that's what you mean?

Comment: and are you sure this is a cryptic clue? and does this come from yourself? it seems like that this puzzle comes from elsewhere. please provide the source. unattributed work may get downvoted or even closed. happy puzzling ;)

Comment: It's my first attempt at such, so it may be way too obvious or way too cryptic, but yes, I believe it meets the usual rules for a cryptic clue. I don't want to explain it yet; that would defeat the purpose. But if no-one gets it then I'll admit defeat and explain how I thought it should work.

Comment: And yes, original.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've just made one change that may help. I need to step away. I'll check back later, see if there are any questions or comments or answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **Rhubarb leaves**
>
>  First, to get rhubarb:
>
>  regret quip = rue barb
>  stage chatter = rhubarb (actors say [rhubarb rhubarb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rhubarb_rhubarb) to mimic background chatter)
>
>  Second, to get leaves:
>
>  goes away = leaves
>  poisonous part of stage chatter (rhubarb) = the leaves of the rhubarb plant, which are poisonous
>
>  The title:
>
>  The red part of the rhubarb plant is edible, the green leaves are poisonous

And how I even figured any of this out:

> I had no idea what "stage chatter" meant but when I searched online for that term, I found out that it was a crossword clue whose answer was "rhubarb".  That didn't make any sense to me so I researched "rhubarb stage chatter" and found out that "rhubarb" was a word repeated by actors to produce background noise/conversation.  That led me to finding out that the leaves of the rhubarb plant were poisonous, etc.  I learned several new things solving this puzzle!